# Is Windows Activation Service + WCF a replacement for COM+

Tags: wcf, architecture, windows-server-2008, com+, was

WAS Features

- Application Pooling
- Recycling
- Idle time management
- Identity Management
- Isolation

Sounds a lot like COM+ but hosted in IIS 7.  Anybody out there using this technology and am I correct comparing the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that WAS offers the sort of distributed transaction management that COM+ and its predecessor, MTS, offered. So WAS is not really a replacement for COM+, though it does offer some of the same features.

Comment: Correct. WCF leverages MSDTC to handle the transactions.  You have to use them in concert.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, that's Microsoft's attempt to allow people use other than HTTP bindings and not bother with self-hosting. .NET and it's set of functionality, Remoting in the early versions of Framework and WCF nowadays are replacement for COM/COM+. WAS is just another solution to host WCF services hassle free with extra functionality.